# Is it possible to return the names of checkboxes in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm currently working with a couple of worksheets that contain hundreds of checkboxes. The code behind these checkboxes works fine, but I'm looking for a way to list the names of the checkboxes per column, i.e. I need to know the names of all checkboxes in column G, for instance.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the TopLeftCell property

```
Sub ListCheckBoxes()

    Dim ole As OLEObject

    'Loop through all the active x controls
    For Each ole In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        'Only care about checkboxes
        If TypeName(ole.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            'Check topleftcell property
            If ole.TopLeftCell.Column = Sheet1.Range("G1").Column Then
                'print out list
                Debug.Print ole.TopLeftCell.Address, ole.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ole

End Sub
```

Comment: I like the way you have used `TypeName` and your use of `TopLeftCell`. A nice, clean solution that looks robust

Answer (score 1):

If you align a control to column G (hold down ALT whilst moving to align) select properties and find out the left position of the control

You can then use this code to identify which controls from `Sheet1` have left alignment equal to what you need.

```
Sub test()
lngcolumnGLeft = 288 'pseudo position of object aligned to column G

'cycle through all objects
With Sheet1

    For Each obj In .OLEObjects
        If obj.Left = lngcolumnGLeft Then

            .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = obj.Name

        End If
    Next obj

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will work if you specify the column you want to check.

For example, if you want to search for all checkboxes in column E you specify `5` and the code checks for any checkbox that is within the bounds of the left most part of column E and column F.

```
Sub ListCheckBoxNames()
    Dim col As Long, cb As OLEObject

    col = 5 //e.g. A=1, B=2, C=3 etc...you need to change this as appropriate

    For Each cb In Worksheets(1).OLEObjects
        If cb.Left >= Columns(col).Left And cb.Left < Columns(col + 1).Left Then
            Debug.Print cb.Name
        End If
    Next cb
End Sub
```