# Excel VBA automatically renaming checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, rename, checkbox

I am currently working on a couple of Excel sheets with a lot of checkboxes.
When you enter a checkbox, it has the name CheckBox1, CheckBox2, etc, but is it possible to automatically rename them? 
In my code, I now have to rename all checkboxes to Rij11_1, Rij11_2, etc.

It would save me a lot of time if this could be done automatically, row by row.

Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards, 
Marc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Checkboxes are on the sheet with codename Sheet1

```
Sub test()

Dim obj As OLEObject, ChkBoxRow as long

ChkBoxRow = 1 'Only change checkboxes with topleft corner in row 1

With Sheet1
'Loop AX controls
For Each obj In .OLEObjects
    'Check for checkbox only
    If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then

        'Examples to identify location (as suggested by Dick Kusleika)
        'ChkBoxRow = obj.TopLeftCell.Row
        'ChkBoxCol = obj.TopLeftCell.Column
        'ChkBoxAdd = obj.TopLeftCell.Address

        'ChkBoxRow = obj.BottomRightCell.Row
        'ChkBoxCol = obj.BottomRightCell.Column
        'ChkBoxAdd = obj.BottomRightCell.Address
        'etc

        if obj.TopLeftCell.Row = ChkBoxRow then
           obj.Name = "Rij11_" & Right(obj.Name, Len(obj.Name) - 8)
        end if

    End If
Next obj
End With
End Sub
```

I've updated showing a nice method [Dick Kusleika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019180/is-it-possible-to-return-the-names-of-checkboxes-in-excel-vba/6020566#6020566) pointed out the other day to locate where the checkboxes reside. You can test for `If obj.TopLeftCell.Row = 1 Then` etc

Comment: Hi Osknows, Thanks for your reply. It's definitely a good start, but it doesn't do the job quite right, i.e. the checkboxes are numbered from 1 to ..., and they aren't necessarily placed in one row consecutively. Is it possible to select a row and rename all checkboxes in that row alone? It's ok for me if I have to select each row separately. Thanks a lot in advance! Kind regards, Marc

Comment: Hi Osknows, could you please enter the entire code as it should be? I'm not a programmer myself, and I am a little confused between your answer and Dick Kusleika's reply. Thanks a lot! Kind regards, Marc

Comment: Hi Osknows, this works perfectly! Thanks a lot! I just noticed that after numbering Rij11_9, I get Rij11_0 and then it starts all over from 1 to 9. 0 should not be included, and the counting should run beyond 9, so from 1 to 27, for instance. Can this be done? Kind regards, Marc

Comment: @Marc, yes, just change `Right(obj.Name, 1)` to `Mid(obj.Name, InStr(obj.Name, "CheckBox") + 8)`.

Comment: @Dave: this doesn't work... I tested it, and the first checkbox in my row had Rij60_570 as a name, instead of Rij60_1. However, after Rij60_579, it gave Rij60_580, so it does continu beyond 9... Kind regards, Marc

Comment: @Dave: the solution with Right(obj.Name, Len(obj.Name) - 8) doesn't work either... Kind regards, Marc

Comment: @Marc, the problem is that you have two different types of names, one for when they're generated by Excel (CheckBox1) and one after they have been modified (Rij60_579), and they're different enough that the names will require two different solutions. I'll modify osknows' answer, but it may still need more work if there are additional cases we have to address.

Comment: @Marc, looking more closely, maybe I am not understanding the issue correctly. As written, osknows' answer should change checkbox names from CheckBox24 to Rij11_24 and so on. If what you need is something that will rename checkboxes and also start renumbering them with 1, then that's a different solution - this answer can be modified to address that, but you should probably modify your question accordingly.

Comment: @Marc try this instead `obj.Name = "Rij11_" & Right(obj.progID, Len(obj.progID) - 15)` It uses the progID which is unchanged even after changing the name

Comment: @Osknows and @Dave: the code now changes the names of all checkboxes, starting with Checkbox1 and running until the last one. I always place the checkboxes in the document column by column, because that is the most logical way my source data dictate. Therefore, the original checkbox numbering in a single row doesn't go like Checkbox1, Checkbox2, ... but rather Checkbox1, Checkbox13, Checkbox37, ... However, the first checkbox in each row should be a number 1, like Rij11_1, Rij24_1, Rij37_1, ... Unregarding of the original checkbox numbers. Does this make it any clearer for you? Kind regards